Can we find tighter upper bound of the following two inequalities on $d$?
Let $d>1$ be a very large integer. I try to find tighter upper bound of the following two inequalities on $d$:
(1)
$$
d^3\log d+d^2\le Cd^3\log d
$$
for some universal constants $C>0$, where I just use $d^2<c d^3\log d$ for some constants $c>0$.
Can we find tighter upper bound, say $C d^2\log d$?
(2) Similarly, consider
$$
d^3\log d+d\le Cd^3\log d
$$
for some universal constants $C>0$.
Can we find tighter upper bound, say $C d^2\log d$, or even better?

$\frac{d^3\log d+d^m}{d^2\log d}=d+\frac{1}{d^{2-m}\log d}\rightarrow \infty$ for $m\le 2$.
